# Regex - Match any word and (preserved) white space, treat parentheses as single word

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for some regex (if possible) to split out a string of words in a specific way.

I've been using `(?!\(.*)\s(?![^(]*?\))` but it just doesn't get me exactly what I want.

This is something super close to what i'm looking for.

```
let message = 'The quick    brown fox (and friend) (jumps over    the) lazy     dog.'
```

```
let result = message.match(/regex/g);
```

Result:

```
[
 'The', 
 'quick', 
 '    ', 
 'brown', 
 ' ', 
 'fox', 
 ' ',
 '(and friend)',
 ' ',
 '(jumps over ( bonus regex - only captures   the most outer parent parentheses) the)', 
 ' ', 
 'lazy', 
 '     ', 
 'dog.'
];
```

Notice the preserved white space and the long parentheses sentence as a single array item.

I've seen questions that look very similar to my own but when I try to modify the answers is seems as though the regex varies greatly regardless of how close my issue is to others. In a nutshell, I'm just really poor at regex.

Thanks for any help with this!

***Edit*** - Added a missed scenario when consecutive parentheses are included in the string.

Comment: If you are going to modify "Result" you need to modify `message` as well. Please state in words what you are trying to do. Do you wish to extract strings delimited by parentheses that contain any number of nested strings delimited by parentheses? If so, while it can be done with a regex, it's much easier to do in code that keeps a count of unmatched left parentheses.

Comment: @peter - Your original regex solved that issue `( abc def  ( hij klm ( abc def  ( hij klm )  opq rst)  )  opq rst)` should be just a single entity. The regex fails to split "consecutive" (not nested) parentheses blocks up into in dependent entities.

Comment: @cary - I'm not sure what you mean by "message". If your referring to the `(jumps over ( bonus regex - only captures   the most outer parent parentheses) the)` block, It was part of my original post. I added the extra `[... '(and friend)' ...] parentheses scenario to my question. As i've mentioned to @peter, his original answer was very close to what I was looking for I just didn't think that the regex would fail to split "consecutive" not "nested" instances of parentheses to into their own entities/items.

Comment: Before your edit you had a variable `message` set equal to a given string. I simply meant that you needed to change that string to be consistent with your desired result. I see that you've done that.

Comment: @cray - I don't think you read it correctly initially. I've only ever edited my original post once. No harm, no foul.

Comment: I read `"( bonus regex - only...)"` as part of the string, `"(jumps over ( bonus regex - only captures   the most outer parent parentheses) the)"`. If that was intended to be a comment, and not meant to be part of that string , you should remove portion that is a comment and then below the array make your point regarding `"(jumps over    the)'"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want: [`(\((?:[^)]*)(?:[^(]*)\))|([\w.,'"!?\\-]+)|(\s+)`](https://regex101.com/r/3BtgrT/3)

```
// Anything inside parentheses
// Matches ( then anything not ), then anything not (, then )
(\((?:[^)]*)(?:[^(]*)\))

// Any word with punctuation
([\w.,'"!?\\-]+)

// Any whitespace
(\s+)
```

As long as the parentheses are matched pairs this should work. After matching you should be able to iterate through the groups.

Comment: @d.breve - You can't get anymore perfect than that. Thanks for your help on this! I also appreciate the break down you provided as well.

Comment: I would like to be enlightened. I Upvoted this answer cause *d.breve* provided a solution based entirely on a single regex that exactly does what the OP did ask for. If someone downvotes an excepted and moreover a technically correct answer I consider this person to pay a minimum of respect to the contributor by also providing an open critique to what actually makes an answer not useful or error prone or for whatever reason disliked.

Answer (score 0):

following regex will be used [`/(\(.*\)|\s+)/`](https://regex101.com/r/OsNqPn/1). The pattern reads like this ...

1. `/( ... )/` ... capture any match like ...
2. either ... `\(.*\)` ... an opening parentheses then everything greedy until the last occurring closing parentheses ...
3. `|` ... or ...
4. `\s+` any whitespace sequence.

```js
const sample = "The quick    brown fox (jumps over ( bonus regex - only captures   the most outer parent parentheses) the) lazy     dog."

const regXSplit = (/(\(.*\)|\s+)/);


console.log(
  'almost the result that was ask for ...',
  sample.split(regXSplit)
);
console.log(
  'the exact result that was ask for via additional filtering ...',
  sample.split(regXSplit).filter(str => !!str)
);

console.log(
  'test viability of both results ...',
   (sample.split(regXSplit).join('') === sample),
   (sample.split(regXSplit).filter(str => !!str).join('') === sample)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The approach beneath takes the new acceptance criteria into account. Thus it provides kind of a minimal *parser* logic in order to support both types of parenthesis enclosed entities, the consecutive and the nested ones ...

```js
const sample = `The quick    brown fox (and friend) (jumps over the) (lazy)     dog.

The quick    brown fox (and friend) (jumps over ( bonus regex - (only captures   the most outer) parent parentheses) the) (lazy)     dog.`;

function parseWordsParenthesisAndWhitespaceSequencesAsEntities(text) {
  function collectOrConcat(collector, token) {

    let { nestingCount, concatenated, list } = collector;

    if (regXLeadingOPT.test(token)) {
      ++nestingCount;
    }
    if (regXTrailingCPT.test(token)) {
      --nestingCount;
    }
    if (nestingCount === 0) {
      if (concatenated !== '') {

        list.push(concatenated + token);

        concatenated = '';
      } else {
        list.push(token);
      } 
    } else {
      concatenated = (concatenated + token);
    }
    collector.nestingCount = nestingCount;
    collector.concatenated = concatenated;

    return collector;
  }
  const regXLeadingOPT = (/^\(/);   // - leading opening parentheses.
  const regXTrailingCPT = (/\)$/);  // - trailing closing parentheses.
  const regXSplit = (/(\([^)(]+\)|\s+)/);

  return text
    .split(regXSplit)
    .filter(str => !!str)
    .reduce(collectOrConcat, {

      nestingCount: 0,
      concatenated: '',
      list: []

    }).list;
}

console.log(
  'just for demonstration purposes of how the new splitting regex works ...',
  'split into smallest tokens, filter empty strings and hope for the best ...',
  sample.split(/(\([^)(]+\)|\s+)/).filter(str => !!str)
);

console.log(
  'provide minimum *parsing* logic due to both consecutive and nested parenthesis ...',
  'parse words parenthesis and whitespace-sequences as entities  ...',
  parseWordsParenthesisAndWhitespaceSequencesAsEntities(sample)
);

console.log(
  'test viability of final parse approach ...',
   (parseWordsParenthesisAndWhitespaceSequencesAsEntities(sample).join('') === sample)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer. It's so dang close to what I need. I know it wasn't included in my "test case" but I just ran a test against what you provided and the only issue I have is that if the there are consecutive parentheses divided by white space, it treats them as a single word.

So if I provide - `'hello world (some test)    (some more test), good bye world.`

I get - `['hello', ' ', 'word', '(some test)   (some more test),' ...]`

Is it possible to split that up?

Comment: @user3180664 ... How should it be split up? What is with nested parenthesis. Are they continued to be treated as entities like with the approach above?

Comment: They aren't nested they're consecutive. I was hoping for something like your original answer, were everything was treated as a single entity. So something like so: `['hello', '  ', 'world', ' ', (some test)', '     ', '(some more test)', ....]`

Right now, I currently get `['hello', '  ', 'world', ' ', (some test)     (some more test)', ....]`.

Comment: @user3180664 ... but from you example ... `'(jumps over ( bonus regex - only captures   the most outer parent parentheses) the)'` ... one very easily can get the impression of nested parenthesis.

Comment: I can see how that can be confusing forsure. It was part of my original post however. The additional request came in the form of - 

`[.... '(and friend)',
 ' ',
 '(jumps over ( bonus regex - only captures   the most outer parent parentheses) the)', ...]`

I included the - "(and friend)" part.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user3180664 ... a second approach is available that meets the new acceptance criteria of recognizing/supporting both types of parenthesis enclosed entities, the consecutive and the nested ones ...

Comment: Another fine answer my good man. I upvoted your initial answer because it definitely got the ball rolling. You've solidified your answer even more. Very much appreciated!